# node_modules outside of the project directory are not transpiled by Babel (7)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-encore

I'm writing an application based on `Symfony4` and `ReactJS` and I'm using the webpack encore to build a bundle. Also the `node_modules` directory is outside the project and is symlinked - probably this is the main culprit but I need to keep `node_modules` outside the project directory.

The issue that I have is related with using some npm packages (eg. `@foes/react-i18n-routing`) that consist of React components / HOCs so they need to be transpiled, but babel not doing this and in the result I'm getting the error similar to this:

```
error  in ./node_modules/@foes/react-i18n-routing/dist/esm/component/withI18nRouting.js

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|
| export default Component => props => (
>   <I18nRoutingContext.Consumer>{context => <Component i18nRouting={context} {...props} />}</I18nRoutingContext.Consumer>
| );
```

As far as I know when I'm using `Babel 7` I need to change my `.babelrc` file to `babel.config.js` to provide the wide project configuration but this is not enough, I'm still facing with the issue.

Can anyone point me the right direction?

I tried a various of configs and I stopped on setting the `babelrcRoots`. Maybe this is the key, but I was not able to set this properly.

Here's the directory structure:

```
ROOT/
├── node_modules/
└── project/
    ├── assets/
    ├── package.json
    ├── babel.config.js
    └── webpack.config.js
```

Here's the `babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'];
  const plugins = [
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties',
    'transform-es2015-modules-commonjs',
    'babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node'
  ];

  // const babelrcRoots = ['.', '../node_modules/*']; ????

  return {
    presets,
    plugins
  };
};
```

And here's the `webpack.config.js`

```
const Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
const path = require('path');

Encore
  .setOutputPath('public/build/')
  .setPublicPath('/build')
  .addEntry('app', './assets/js/app.jsx')
  .splitEntryChunks()
  .enableSingleRuntimeChunk()
  .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
  .enableBuildNotifications()
  .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
  .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
  .enableLessLoader()
  .enableReactPreset();


let config = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
config.resolve.alias['App'] = path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/js');
// config.resolve.modules = [path.resolve('./node_modules'), path.resolve('../node_modules')]; here's the another try with no luck

module.exports = config;
```

And here's the `package.json`

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.27.0",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.2.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "core-js": "^3.0.0",
    "less-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.4.4",
    "@foes/react-i18n-routing": "^0.8.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.9.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.12.1",
    "history": "^4.9.0",
    "lodash.flatmap": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.0.0",
    "react-router-named-routes": "0.0.23"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try configuring to `rootMode:"upward"` setting mentioned [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files) like so:

```
babel --root-mode upward src -d lib
```

or in webpack

```
module: {
        rules: [{
            loader: "babel-loader",
            options: {
                rootMode: "upward",
            }
        }]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! After adding the babel-loader with rootMode "upward" option to my webpack config the webpack runs without any errors. Now I have another issue, but this is probably related with "@foes/react-i18n-routing" npm package so I created a new issue there ( https://github.com/FriendsOfECMAScript/ReactI18nRouting/issues/22 )